# Retrieve a Value from a id based on tree structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Goal:
When you press a specific button for instance button id="button_a", you should retrieve the value from id="a1" and then it should display as alert message.

Problem:
When you have a table between 100 and 200 rows, you cannot hard code the specific id name in the javascript.

Question:
How should you retrieve the value of the for instance id="a1" when you have pressed the button?

I have tried and learned that you use  "previousSibling" (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_previoussibling) but it more complicated that I have expected.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><div id="a1"><div id="aa1">aa1</div></div></td>
    <td><div id="a2"><div id="aa2">aa2</div></div></td>
    <td><button id="button_a"></button></td>
    <td></td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div id="b1"><div id="bb1">bb1</div></div></td>
    <td><div id="b2"><div id="bb2">bb2</div></div></td>
    <td><button id="button_b"></button></td>
    <td></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div id="c1"><div id="cc1">cc1</div></div></td>
    <td><div id="c2"><div id="cc2">cc2</div></div></td>
    <td><button id="button_c"></button></td>
    <td></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div id="d1"><div id="dd1">dd1</div></div></td>
    <td><div id="d2"><div id="dd2">dd2</div></div></td>
    <td><button id="button_d"></button></td>
    <td></td>       
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right you want the value of first `div` inside `tr` on button click. You can use:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var val = $(this) //referes to the dom element, in this case the button
    .parents("tr") //get ancestor tr of the clicked element(button)
    .find("td:first-child > div") //find first td that has direct child div
    .text(); //get the text value of the div element
    $(this).after("<span>" + val + "</span>");//for test purposes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="a1">
        <div id="aa1">aa1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="a2">
        <div id="aa2">aa2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="button_a">Click!</button>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="b1">
        <div id="bb1">bb1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="b2">
        <div id="bb2">bb2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="button_b">Click!</button>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="c1">
        <div id="cc1">cc1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="c2">
        <div id="cc2">cc2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="button_c">Click!</button>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="d1">
        <div id="dd1">dd1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="d2">
        <div id="dd2">dd2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="button_d">Click!</button>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**References**

[.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

[:first-child](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: @HelloWorld Glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

With the jQuery you can navigate by tree easily. What you can do it the following:

```
$('#button_a').on('click', function(e) {
    var div_a1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('div').first();
    // and so on
}
```

Read more at [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)